# Error while uploading a theme - The site can't be reached

Tags: wordpress

I am working with a small start-up and know little about web design etc. However, given that I am on a shoe string budget, I am trying to create a simple one page site to attract prospective employees.

I have a site hosted on Godaddy wordpress plan. Having set up the account etc, I am trying to upload a theme - Tesseract. I have downloaded the theme from the site as a zip file.

However, everytime I try to upload it through my wordpress admin panel, I am eventually directed to

my_site_name/wp-admin/update.php?action=upload-theme

and the browser says "The site cant be reached. The connection was reset" (my_site_name is the name of my registered site)

Having unsuccessfully searched for the solution online, I have tried to figure things out with the Godaddy support staff. They suggested that I try to manually put the theme folder onto the server using FTP and they guided me to do so. The theme was then supposed to turn up on my installed themes and I could activate it from there.

However, even after the file transfer, the theme still does not show up. I have used this theme before for another website and found it better in terms of customisation of colours etc. Hence I am trying to figure out if I can use this again.

Can anyone help in resolving this?

Thanks
Sid

Comment: Have u updated database connection after uploading on server?

Comment: Dear Vinit,
Thanks for your response. Just to update, there seemed to have been an issue at godaddy's end. They have corrected it and now the site works fine.